# MudDataGrid row select using SelectColumn doesnt display

Tags: mudblazor

(MudBlazor 6.6.0, dotnet core 6.0)

I have constructed my first MudDataGrid based on an observable collection of 'product's

```
public partial class Product
{
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    public decimal? Price { get; set; }
    public decimal? Quantity { get; set; }
    public long ProductId { get; set; }
}
```

and my grid

```
<MudDataGrid MultiSelection="true" Items="observableProducts" ReadOnly="false" EditMode="DataGridEditMode.Cell">
    <Columns>
        <SelectColumn T="Product" />
        <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.Name" Title="Name" />
        <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.Price" Title="Price" />
        <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.Quantity" Title="Quantity" />
    </Columns>
</MudDataGrid>
```

based on https://mudblazor.com/components/datagrid#advanced-data-grid

but I get no 'select' tickbox on the row, I get one in the column title and footer.

[image: grid with no tick box]

What am I missing? do the items in the grid need to implement some attribute to track selection?

(I can't find any significant docs except the the one stated, which demonstrates techniques but leaves out some of the details)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `<MudDataGrid MultiSelection="true" Items="observableProducts" ReadOnly="false" EditMode="DataGridEditMode.Cell">`

Since you've added a `ReadOnly="false"` & `EditMode="DataGridEditMode.Cell"` This means that the DataGrid cells are always in an editing state therefore, the tickbox will not show.

You will have to change either of these properties in order for the multiselect tickbox to show.

[MudBlazor snippet](https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/ckQRErOKMucgYZcu)

Comment: so can i have an editable grid with checkboxes?
is it more sensible to have a 'isselected' bool in the element in the collection?

Comment: It seems that even though the checkbox isn't being displayed the row is still being selected/unselected, when the `MultiSelection` property is set to true. This is bound to cause issues.

Comment: Here is a [snippet](https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/GOmRkhaUAbMjjvgu) where we create our own checkbox column instead of using the `SelectColumn`. Although this also seems to be facing the same issue where the CheckBox is only visible when`ReadOnly` is true. However, since the RowClick event hasn't been bound it doesn't select/unselect the row when editing.

Comment: ah ok, thats really good, but even in your snippet, if the grid is not readonly the check box doesnt appear? This seems odd, I want to be able to edit all the attributes of a record being displayed, and 1 of them happens to be a bool.

Comment: Well I can't find a way to display the checkbox **and** also edit the cells at the same time. Unless someone finds a way to make it work, best option would be to use an **_Editable/Selectable_** mode. [snippet](https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/ckQRErOKMucgYZcu) . Still keeps track of the selection, just doesn't show the checkbox.

Comment: And boolean properties not being editable, seems to be a known [issue](https://github.com/MudBlazor/MudBlazor/pull/7093) and is being patched. That change might also "fix" how the select checkbox interacts.

Comment: ok, I'll mark this response as the answer. I find it odd that this grid does all sorts of things, but doesnt allow you to edit a bool via a checkbox, I think that is really my underlying issue. I'll bodge something for the moment and return to it later.

Comment: actually this isnt the answer, the snippet doesnt set the value IsSelected, so I copied the example from the mudblazor documentation that shows there is a handler to handle when the selection changes (and you basically track it with a hashset attribute)

Comment: @MrDatKookerellaLtd the snippet on my answer is only for your original question without the `IsSelected` property, I haven't bound the IsSelected property to anything hence that property is not being changed. It needs to be added as a `<PropertyColumn>` or using the `SelectedItemsChanged` EventCallback, however since the `MudDataGrid` doesn't support bool values at the moment it would be redundant to add it as a PropertyColumn and yes you can use the EventCallback to alter it.